# Using http response headers in order to communicate server-side errors from the backend to the front-end

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, servlets

I am working on a REST backend consumed by a javascript/ajax front-end.

I am trying to find a way to deal with invalid requests sent over by the front-end to the backend.

One of the issues I have is that HTTP status codes such as (`400`, `409`) are not fine-grained enough to cover business logic errors such as passwords not matching (in the case of a user changing his password) or an email being unknown to the system (in the case of a user trying to signin with the application).

I am thinking of using **HTTP response headers** in order to communicate server-side error from the backend to the front-end.

I could for instance have an `Error` enum (or a class with constants) as follows:

```
public enum Error {
 UNKNOWN_EMAIL,
 PASSWORDS_DONT_MATCH,
 //etc.
}
```

I would then use that enum in order to set the headers on the response as follows:

```
response.setHeader(Error.UNKNOWN_EMAIL.name(), "true");
```

... and deal with the error appropriately on the front-end.

Can the above architecture be improved? If so how?

Is my usage of HTTP response headers correct?

Should I use constants or enums?

Comment: Depending how many different errors you want to render to the user you might have the webservice return a JSON which contains an error number or text. Only using http status code might become difficult to handle

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't use http status codes but http headers.

Comment: Updated my answer with some more detail. Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Is my usage of HTTP response headers correct?

I do not think it is incorrect, however I prefer to send an error message/code directly back in the response body. This is usually more convenient for the client to access and is more explicit. As part of consuming each response, the client can check the contents of the errors (you may have multiple) and act accordingly.  The following is a little contrived just to provide an example:

```
// ...
{ 
    "errors": {
        "username": "not found"
        "password": "no match"
    }
    "warnings": {
        "account": "expired"
    }
}
// ...
```

The above is quite a simple approach - your JSON message can be as sophisticated as you wish but keep in mind that you should only expose the information the client needs for it to achieve its goal. This will also depend on whether you are publishing an API for 3rd parties/public consumption or whether its just for your own clients ie. your own website. If you have other parties consuming it then put some thought into it since once you publish it then you need to maintain it that way - otherwise you break any consumers.

Check out [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors-processing) for some standardized guidance on handling errors.

> Should I use constants or enums?

Since these are a related set of properties an enum is preferable over constants (I assume you are using Java).

Comment: Thanks! Can you please provide a code sample demonstrating how you would set multiple errors on the response? Yes I do use java & servlets through Spring mvc.

Comment: Would you set the json in the message param of the following method? See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int, java.lang.String)